# kubernetes internal to external communication directly?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to access some external Saas api endpoints in pod.  I use flannel as kubernetes network.  But when I try to ping external IP in a pod, the packet will be sent without masquerading. So ping could not be successful

And I found this: 
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html
  After creating the service without selector and attach the related endpoint, I could get the external service in pod.

I could also add the iptables masquerade on 10.254.0.0/16 on node to enable directly accessing external endpoint as follows:

```
 iptables -t nat -A -A POSTROUTING -s 10.254.61.0/24 ! -d 10.254.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
```

But couldn't we just access the external Saas endpoint directly?

Is there any configuration on kubernetes or flannel(or other network plugin?)  that can allow  internal-to-external communication directly?

Thanks

Comment: In kubernetes documents about networking, I also found this [link](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/networking.html#google-compute-engine-gce) . Does this means iptables masquerade is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kubelet will ensure the iptables postrouting rule is created if you tell it to [1] however I suspect you're running with --configure-cbr0=false because you want to allow flannel to set up container networking. I believe you can tell flannel to set the rule for you:

> flanneld --help
>   ...
>   -ip-masq
>           setup IP masquerade rule for traffic destined outside of overlay network

[1] https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9cfab87e33ea649bdd13a1bd243c502d76e5d22/pkg/kubelet/container_bridge.go#L122

Comment: Thanks,  exactly what I want.  Flanneld could  set ip-masq  now according to your help